# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Community Building's [first moderator election](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: ChrisF]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes! [Um. Maybe the template isn't appropriate here. ;-) ]

Also, please join me in thanking Anonymous Penguin who will be stepping down as moderator.

Since this is a [*pro tempore* election](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/announcing-a-pro-tempore-election), ChrisF would need to run again if we ever have a graduation election.

Comment: Congratulations Chris!  It's great to have you on board.

Comment: Anonymous Penguin, thanks for all you've done for this site over the last several years!

Comment: Ropes? You mean there are actual ropes?

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes. They are routed through series of tubes.

Comment: Welcome to the team Chris!